# Counting objects based on nested key value

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

**EDITED**
I have this nested json and I want to search for a value then return the whole object where this value was found and count those object and recreate the object using map and filter. I don't know  what to do it since I'm kinda newbie in programming.

In the example json I want to search for values of fruits and then count all the total objects with value of those fruits with dates.

Sample Json object:

```
var sampleData = [
 {
   fruitData: {
     fruit: 'apple',
     price: 23
   },
   dateCreated: '2019-07-23T00:20:36.535Z'
 },
 {
   fruitData: {
     fruit: 'apple',
     price: 36 
   },
   dateCreated: '2019-07-23T00:30:32.135Z'
 },
 {
   fruitData: {
     fruit: 'apple',
     price: 36 
   },
   dateCreated: '2019-07-24T00:10:36.115Z'
 },
 {
   fruitData: {
     fruit: 'mango',
     price: 40 
   },
   dateCreated: '2019-07-24T01:25:32.835Z'
 },
]
```

I expect the output to be like this and count after searching for value of fruits

```
var filteredData= [
 {
   '07-23-2019': {
       'apple': 2
   },
   '07-24-2019': {
       'apple': 1,
       'mango': 1
   }
 }
]
```

Thank you for those who will help

Comment: Is the data always in that format?

Comment: yes, it will be always in this format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the JSON is structured, we can get the value of fruits:

```js
function fruitCount(sampleData) {
    var results = {};

    // sampleData is a list, so for each item
    sampleData.forEach((container) => {

        // Get the relevant data from the subfields.
        let date = container.dateCreated;
        let fruit = container.fruitData.fruit;

        // If the date has been found before, we'll reuse it.
        // If the fruit has been found before, we'll increment it.
        // If the fruit has NOT been found before, we'll insert it with a
        //     value of 1.
        if (date in results) {
            results[date][fruit] = results[date][fruit] + 1 || 1;

        // The date has not been found before, so create it.
        } else {
            results[date] = {fruit: 1};
        }
    });

    return results;
}
```

```js
if (date in results) {
    results[date][fruit] = results[date][fruit] + 1 || 1;
```

Is equivalent to

```js
if (date in results) {
    if (fruit in results[date]) {
        results[date][fruit]++;
    } else {
        results[date][fruit] = 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Michael, this works too.. thanks for another solution. but can this be achieve using array.filter() and array.map()? I want to up vote but I cant because I am below 15 reputation.

Comment: sorry i change the output see the sample on my edited topic, I forgot that the date should also be included..

Comment: thank you, one last thing, can you explain to me each line of the code? Using comments in the code It will be a big help to me.

Answer (score 2):

```
const sampleData = [
    {
        fruitData: {
            fruit: 'apple',
            price: 23
        },
        dateCreated: '07-23-2019'
    },
    {
        fruitData: {
            fruit: 'apple',
            price: 36
        },
        dateCreated: '07-23-2019'
    },
    {
        fruitData: {
            fruit: 'mango',
            price: 40
        },
        dateCreated: '07-23-2019'
    },
];


function groupData(data, key) {
    const objs = {};
    for (const obj of data) {
        objs[obj[key].fruit] = (objs[obj[key].fruit] || 0) + 1;
    }
    return objs;
}

const data = groupData(sampleData, 'fruitData');
```

if you want data to be an array then change the last line to this

```
const data = [groupData(sampleData, 'fruitData')];
```

Comment: Hi Jamal, this works too.. thanks for another solution. but can this be achieve using array.filter() and array.map()? I want to up vote but I cant because I am below 15 reputation.

Comment: sorry i change the output see the sample on my edited topic, I forgot that the date should also be included..